# Runing R code on `python` with SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression error Message

Tags: python, r, rpy2, statistics

I'm looking to run some `R` code on `python`

I already installed the R package `robustbase` on ubunto using `apt-get install r-cran-robustbase` and rpy packege as well.

from the python console I can successfully run `from rpy import *` and  `r.library("robustbase")`
but when I run

```
result = robjects.FloatVector([11232.1, 234.2, 3445532344.3, 34302.3, 203.9, 232223.3, 3434.55])
print(result.r_repr())
r(adjboxStats(c(11232.1, 234.2, 3445532344.3, 34302.3, 203.9, 232223.3, 3434.55), coef = 2.5, a = -4, b = 3, do_conf = TRUE, do_out = TRUE))
```

to get the outliers values

But I get this error :

```
adjboxStats(c(11232.1, 234.2, 3445532344.3, 34302.3, 203.9, 232223.3, 3434.55), coef = 2.5, a = -4, b = 3, do.conf = TRUE, do.out = TRUE)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

when I run this on R console it works!!!

```
library("robustbase")
adjboxStats(c(11232.1, 234.2, 3445532344.3, 34302.3, 203.9, 232223.3, 3434.55), coef = 2.5, a = -4, b = 3, do.conf = TRUE, do.out = TRUE)
```

I search [here](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/vector.html) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607698/statistics-tests-kolmogorov-and-t-test-with-python-and-rpy2?) and [here](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/introduction.html#creating-rpy2-vectors) but no luck.
doesn anyone knows what is that error message for and is there's a way to go arround it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `do.conf` or `do.out` as arguments to a Python function (even if the function will be converted to R).

Comment: correct, I have to use do_conf and do_out right? this much I know :)

Comment: @mongotop: If you already know that, why not make that change (which will fix this error) instead of asking?

Comment: it didn't fix the issue, so I decided to post the original code and ask the experts

Comment: Where is `adjboxStats` defined?

Comment: it's inside `robustbase`

Comment: You meant to do `r("adjboxStats")`, but see my answer for the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `do.conf` or `do.out` as arguments to a Python function (even if the function will be converted to R).

Instead, call them `do_conf` and `do_out`. You were then getting tripped up by another error, which is how you refer to `r("adjboxStats")`:

```
r("adjboxStats")(result, coef = 2.5, a = -4, b = 3, do_conf = True, do_out = True)
```

This will fix the syntax issues.

Comment: it did!!! and it answer my question, and I will mark it as accepted!!! thanks a lot, can I ask you a another question indie please, what do I get c is not defined error? I'm just using as a vector as I read here http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/robustbase/html/adjboxStats.html

Comment: `c` is an `R` function and it is not a Python function. Instead use `r.c`.

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much! I tried r.c and my code stop on executing, the execution wont finish and it hang and i have to kill the process every time I run the script, do you have any idea why this might be happening for? thank you very much again!!

Comment: @mongotop Could you post this as a new question, including an entirely reproducible example? That is- it should have a snippet of Python code that, as long as someone runs that exact code and has rpy2 installed (and robustbase installed) it should give the same error?

Comment: @mongotop: Oh- it looks like you just did

Comment: yes :) here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569105/what-is-the-python-numpy-or-scipy-or-pandas-equivalent-for-rs-adjboxstats-fun for future.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30009/discussion-between-mongotop-and-david-robinson)